# How to convert timezone inside bindings?

Tags: java, drools

I tried to calculate unfinished downtime duration. Start time is stored in GMT timezone and finish time is local datetime in my timezone (GMT+2 or GMT+3). I want to calculate difference in seconds.

Null datetime is 1900-01-01 00:00:00, so I have expression that means start time is after end time to find unfinished downtimes. Than I get current time and convert it into epoch seconds consigering timezone difference and subtract start time converted into epoch seconds.

In code it looks like

```
LoadingDowntimes 
   (globalobjectid == $CurrentDowntimeGOId && 
   downtimeend.toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.ofHours(0)) < downtimestart.toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.ofHours(0)), 
   $DowntimesTimeUnfinished : (LocalDateTime.now().toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.ofHours($CurrentZoneOffset.offset)) - downtimestart.toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.ofHours(0))))
```

All parts of this code work corretly in another places, but in this place I have error message

```
Variables can not be used inside bindings. 
Variable [$CurrentZoneOffset] is being used in binding '(LocalDateTime.now().toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.ofHours($CurrentZoneOffset.offset)) - StringToLocalDateTime(downtimestart).toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.ofHours(0)))'
```

I don't know how to make it another way so I need a help with solving this problem.

Comment: Take a look at the `Duration` class.  I believe it has a `between` method that might be what you're looking for.  `Duration.between(LocalDateTime1,LocalDateTime1).toMillis()*1000`

Comment: Voting to close as unclear. I cannot even begin to decode your sample code. Describe your actual objects in play - what class, what values, hat meaning. Eliminate all irrelevant code. Also, I cannot imagine any situation where calling `LocalDateTime.now` is the right thing to do. That class cannot represent a moment, is *not* a point in the timeline, as explained in its Javadoc.